# Freestyle svg exporting long paths that extend way out of the rendering area

Tags: freestyle, svg

I have a wireframe I'm attempting to export from blender -> svg in inkscape -> pen plotter, but I can't find a way to "crop" or cut the wireframe so that it's bounded within the render.

[Inkscape screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXpvf.png)

[Blender screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybAF1.png)

I've attempted to crop them in inkscape, but unfortunately the normal cropping workflow just hides the cropped portion of the paths, and my pen plotter still attempts to draw them. So I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it in blender without mangling my scene. (so that I can export different views of it easily)

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: I chose to leave them as links because they were large and made the post kind of ugly