# View clip an object permanently

Tags: modeling, rendering, svg

I want to clip an object with [view clipping](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html) as a solution to [this svg export problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161350/85677), but when I render the view clipped object as an svg, I still get the unclipped version of the svg. So I was wondering if there's a way to permanently view clip the object, and maybe create a new scene with just that clipped object that I can then render.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to go in edit mode of the path. select the part that you only want to show, and separate it into its own object by pressing [P]

Alternatively you can try to use a Boolean modifier with intersect to non destructively cut down an object.

you might also try using culling with objects during render time: [Culling Objects Using a Culling Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73930/culling-objects-using-a-culling-object)

Comment: Or use a  mask in the compositor.